# Normal Distribution of a csv file variable in R

Tags: r

I want to generate a normal distribution of a variable from a csv file. 
I read the file using the following command

```
f <- read.csv("./data/file.csv")
```

I can generate a general normal distribution using the following command

```
curve(dnorm, from = -3, to = 3, main = "Normal")
```

However, can't find on how to get the normal distribution of the variable 'x' from the file.csv

Comment: This `how to get the normal distribution of the variable 'x' ` does not make sense.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to create a histogram? See `?hist`.